# React Native Android: How to display image and text in one row?

Tags: react-native, material-ui, jsx

I have tried to create react native app for android where child image and name will display in one line. You can check it on [rawgit](https://cdn.rawgit.com/dabbott/react-native-web-player/gh-v2.0.0-alpha.3/index.html#code=import%20React%2C%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20'react'%0Aimport%20%7B%20AppRegistry%2C%20Text%2C%20View%2C%20Image%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20App%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style%3D%7B%7B%20textAlign%3A%20'left'%2C%20fontSize%3A%2015%2C%20backgroundColor%3A'grey'%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CImage%20source%3D%7B%7Buri%3A%20'https%3A%2F%2Fleaderbord-552b1.firebaseapp.com%2FAdminLTE%25202%2520_%2520User%2520Profile_files%2Fmount-carmel-logo.png'%7D%7D%20style%3D%7B%7Bwidth%3A%2070%2C%20height%3A%2070%2C%20borderRadius%3A70%7D%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style%3D%7B%7B%20backgroundColor%3A'lightblue'%2C%20%7D%7D%3EVindhyachal%3C%2FText%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('App'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20App)%0A).

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { AppRegistry, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
           <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
                            <Image source={{uri: 'https://leaderbord-552b1.firebaseapp.com/AdminLTE%202%20_%20User%20Profile_files/mount-carmel-logo.png'}} style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius:70}} />
                            <Text style={{ backgroundColor:'lightblue', }}>Vindhyachal</Text> 
                        </Text>
          </View>     
        )
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

I am getting below output which is wrong, text is displaying at bottom instead of same line at middle.

[image]

Note:- I can't change the component structure because I am using it in react-native-material-ui-demo-app [Drawer](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui/blob/master/docs/Drawer.md) as below.

```
    <Drawer.Section
        divider
        items={[
            { value: <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
                        <Image source={{uri: child.image'}} style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius:70}} />
                        <Text style={{ backgroundColor:'lightblue', }}>{child.name}</Text> 
                    </Text> },
            { value: <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
                        <Image source={{uri: child.image'}} style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius:70}} />
                        <Text style={{ backgroundColor:'lightblue', }}>{child.name}</Text> 
                    </Text> }
        ]}
    />
```

Below is screenshot of my app where I am facing this issue.

[image]

I'll be grateful if someone can help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: on `<View>` below `return()` add `style={{flexDirection:'row'}}` , and don't realize <Text> can be nested, xD

Comment: @flix I have tried, it is not working as expected

Comment: and also add `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` and try

Comment: @AravindS It is not html, I have tried with this style style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}

Comment: my bad! you are giving to `View` only right? can you remove the `Text` next to the `View` and try

Comment: Thanks @AravindS it works! but I can't remove Text because I am using it in prop name 'item' of component '<Drawer.Section' material-ui

Comment: happy to know that!...can i add it as answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176407/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-vindhyachal-kumar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by two ways as follows:
   1] With inner Text block removed (Just need to add alignSelf: "center" to your Text) as follows:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
    <Image source={{uri: 'https://leaderbord-552b1.firebaseapp.com/AdminLTE%202%20_%20User%20Profile_files/mount-carmel-logo.png'}} style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius:70}} />
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor:'lightblue', alignSelf: "center" }}>Vindhyachal</Text>
</View>
```

2] Without Text removed using your existing Drawer.Section code (Need to provide float:"left" style and positioning your Text as absolute with top value) as follows:

```
<Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'grey', alignItems:"center", float:"left", position:"absolute"}}>
    <Image source={{uri: 'https://leaderbord-552b1.firebaseapp.com/AdminLTE%202%20_%20User%20Profile_files/mount-carmel-logo.png'}} style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius:70, float:"left"}} />
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor:'lightblue', float:"left", position:"absolute", top:"45%"}}>{child.name}</Text> 
</Text>
```

Comment: output of 2nd solution is not same as 1st. Is it possible to make left (image) - right (Text) without Text removed?

Comment: @Vindhyachal Kumar, I have tested both and result are same. Please use this url and add above code with adding required imports. Url: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

Comment: @Vindhyachal Kumar, If it is not working for you, may I know how it is being displayed? So that I will do relevant changes to make it work.

Comment: Ok, will check.

Comment: @Vindhyachal Kumar, I have updated my 2nd point in answer. Please check the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I've used to handle what you need:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text, View, Image
} from 'react-native';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';

const DeviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const DeviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', width:DeviceWidth, height:DeviceWidth*0.5, alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Image source={{uri : 'someUrl'}} 
        style={{width:DeviceWidth*0.5, height:DeviceWidth*0.5, resizeMode:'contain'}}/>
        <Text>Next to Image</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default MyClass;
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the updated code where moving the flex styling to the `View` tag. Sharing a [URL](http://flexboxfroggy.com) where you can play with flex.

```
    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
           <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'grey'}}>
                <Image source={{uri: 'https://leaderbord-552b1.firebaseapp.com/AdminLTE%202%20_%20User%20Profile_files/mount-carmel-logo.png'}} style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius:70}} />
                <Text style={{ backgroundColor:'lightblue', }}>Vindhyachal</Text> 
             </Text>
          </View>     
        )
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```